# TSQL having @varible in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014, concatenation

Hey all here is my code that I currently have in a Stored Proceedure:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
[more code here.....]

SET @SQL = @ParameterSQL;
[more code here.....]

SET @SQL = 
     'SELECT 
        CONCAT(
                OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID), 
                LEFT(modify_date, 11), 
                '' ('', 
                DATEDIFF(day, LEFT(modify_date, 11), GETDATE()), 
                '' days ago)''
              ) AS CurrentVersion,
        CONCAT(
                ''@val3'',
                ''''
              ) AS calledQuery 
      FROM 
        sys.objects
      WHERE 
        type = ''P''
      AND 
        name = ''' + @ver + '''';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

No error but in the output it just shows this:

```
_______________________________________
|CurrentVersion           |calledQuery|
|-------------------------|-----------|
|May 11 2017 (0 days ago) |@val3      |
```

So that @val3 should be a query that was just ran.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You should use parameters:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@val3 nvarchar(max)', @val3 = @val3;
```

I don't know what the exact definition or name of the `@val3`, so you may need to modify the above for the actual variable you are using and its type.

And, you probably don't want the double quotes around `@val3` in the query.  In fact, I don't think you want the `concat()` at all: